# Radio button/checkbox array not displaying saved values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For loop post to db works fine. Retrieving value from bool property saved in model works as well. However, when user goes to edit, the view is not showing saved values in the array. So the issue is binding the saved boolean values to the array.

```
 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
  {

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Answers[i].QuestionID, new { id = Model.Questions[i].QuestionID })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Answers[i].ApplicationID, new { id = Model.ApplicationID })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Answers[i].QuestionText, new { id = Model.Questions[i].QuestionText })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Answers[i].QuestionCategoryID, new { id = Model.Questions[i].QuestionCategoryID })
             @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Answers[i].ResponseBool, true) Yes


  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Answers[i].ResponseBool, false) No

        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Questions[i].QuestionText, new { @class = "col-md-2" })
    }
```

I am accessing the questions and answer repos through my viewmodel:

```
 Questions = new QuestionRepository().GetStepOneQuestions();

        Answers = new ResponseRepository().GetStepOneResponses(stepOneSaved.ApplicationID)
             .Select(k => new Response()
            {
                ApplicationID = stepOneSaved.ApplicationID,
                QuestionID = k.QuestionID,
                QuestionCategoryID = k.QuestionCategoryID,
                QuestionText = k.QuestionText,
                ResponseBool = k.ResponseBool
            })
            .ToList();
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult StepOne(int id)
        {
                var application = _applicationData.GetByID(id);
                var form = _eduInfoData.GetByEdID(id);

                var vm = new StepOneViewModel(application, form);
                    return View(vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult StepOne( StepOneViewModel form)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = form.toEduInfo();
                if (ModelState.IsValid && _eduInfoData.TrySave(item))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < form.Answers.Count; i++)
                    {
                        _responseData.TrySave(form.ApplicationID, form.Answers[i]);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("StepTwo", new { id = item.ApplicationID });
                }
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(form);
        }
```

Comment: Show you controller code so we can understand what your doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! problem was I not pulling back the responses correctly.To fix I passed in the appId and questionId into my response model,and set the values there.

still needs some re-factoring but here's the gist of it:

```
    public Response(int id, int qID)
            {
                this.ResponseBool = new ResponseRepository().GetResponse(id).Where(m => m.QuestionID == qID).Select(m => m.ResponseBool).FirstOrDefault();
    }

      Answers = Questions
                     .Select(k => new Response(stepOneSaved.ApplicationID, k.QuestionID)
                    {
                        ApplicationID = stepOneSaved.ApplicationID,
                        QuestionID = k.QuestionID,
                        QuestionCategoryID = k.QuestionCategoryID,
                        QuestionText = k.QuestionText,
                    })
                    .ToList();
```